# $11^n$ in Pascals triangle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

*Let all rows begin with  $1$*

*Let all rows be calculated from right to left*

*Let row A and B be constants*

*Let row C and D be permutations*

*if $A+B>9$*, $C-10$, $D+1$

```
  B   A
D   C
```

$$A+B=C$$

Result: $11, 121, 1331, 14641,161051$...

$$11$$$$121$$$$1331$$$$14641$$$$161051$$$$1771561$$$$19487171$$$$214358881$$

Why does this method only work for $11$?

Comment: Let us begin with the easiest question : The ending digit is alwys $1$ since $11^n\equiv 1^n=1\mod 10$. That the Pascal triangle structure soon breaks down is the consequence of carries.

Comment: $11^n=(1+10)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk 10^k$

Comment: I think you could state the questions more clearly by eliminating "this" from them

Comment: @Barb I still don't understand what 'this' in 'how do I prove this?' referencing to. What do you want to proof?

Answer (score 1):

That's multiplication by $11$

```
   19487171 * 11
   -------------
   19487171
  + 19487171
   ---------
   214358881
```

So you get the most right 8 in the result either by doing the pascal triangle like calculation

```
 194871|7+1|
2143588| 8 |1
```

or by doing the usual multiplication by 11

```
   19487171 * 11
   -------------
   1948717|1|
          |+|
  + 194871|7|1
   ---------
   2143588|8|1
```

So the pascal triangle method is only a method to avoid writing down the number twice as it is done during the usual multiplication. In both cases you add two neighbored numbers an maybe a carry from the preceding addition.

Comment: @Barb Note that the similarity of the calculation of the pascal triangle and of the simple the multiplication by 11 I have  shown in my post.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works for any number, if weightings are applied. If you multiply the left by 20 and add 3 times the right, you will get powers of 23.

In any case, the additional row is produced in the form 10(x)+(y), which is the same formula as multiplying by 1,1.

Edit...

To do powers of 23,

```
         1                      A     B
     2       3                   3A+2B
  4      12     9 
8    48     54    27
```

This comes in quite handy in allowing for example one to find powers of numbers like 2003, or the element consist of things like cubes (which starts with 2A+B).  There are lots of triangles that work by adjusting the multipliers across the row.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example of the multiplicative part in your answer please Wendy? I want to understand the relation